# Convert an object of a Class to XLang Message

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I need to convert a Class object to Xlang message.Because I need to pass this as a parameter to one of the methods as XLANG type
Example

```
Class obj= new Class();

XLangMessage xlang=null;

xlang=obj;
```

How can I convert anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx) operator as a method in `Class`:

```
public static implicit operator XLangMessage(Class obj)
{
    XLangMessage x = new XLangMessage();

    // write conversion here
    x.Prop = obj.Prop;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: @user2742746: need more help?

Comment: @user2742746: if you don't need help on this any more, please don't forget to mark the question answered by accepting it.